# Maven and Android cannot find class CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer

Tags: android, maven

I am trying to get an example Android app to run. The app uses Maven to manage the project.  When I run the project I receive the following error:

```
Could not find class 'oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer', referenced from method....
```

However in the pom.xml file I have

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>1.6_r2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
            <artifactId>signpost-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.1</version>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
            <artifactId>signpost-commonshttp4</artifactId>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Given the dependency can be resolved at compile time because it is clearly in the dependency list, what do I need to do to solve the runtime error?

I'm using Windows 7, JDK 1.6, Eclipse Indigo (with the Maven addon)

Thanks,
Jack

I have just noticed that when viewing my pom file in Eclipse using m2e with the "Dependencies" view (not raw xml). I see:

```
android:1.6_r2:jar [provided]
signpost-core:1.2.1.1 [compile]
json:20090211:jar [compile]
signpost-commonshttp4
```

The string identifying the dependency doesn't seem complete, there is no type or version number, it also doesn't display the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some [dependencyManagement](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) going on, your signpost-commonshttp4 artifact needs a version.

Comment: I modified the dependency to include:<version>1.2.1.1</version> however I still get the error (I used http://search.maven.org to look up the version number)

Comment: So what does "when I run the project" mean, exactly? However you're running, it seems that the oauth jar isn't on the classpath.

Comment: When the apk is deployed to the device and started. At runtime, the class cannot be found.

Comment: I do not understand how it could not be on the classpath, since the dependency is defined with scope 'compile' in the pom.xml file. So it should be on the classpath.

Comment: I have extracted the generated .apk and used a tool to unpack classes.dex. I can see the file CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer.ddx is packaged into my apk, and the .ddx file specifies the java source file CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer.java  

So it seems the libraries / classes are being included. I am even more confused why the class cannot be found at runtime!

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found where I was going wrong. I thought I could use Eclipse 'as normal' to build and debug my app, but I can't. I need to run a Maven command which uses the android plugin to install the apk onto the device (not Eclipse).

Once the app is installed I can then launch the app on the device and use DDMS in Eclipse to debug the app.  The command  I run is:

```
mvn install android:deploy
```

I found the following page of the [mvn-android-plugin wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Debug) useful.